# Using a function that return multiple rows and values in pandas apply()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm going through a big dataset with a function that returns multiple values from just one input row just like this:

```
def function(row):
  res_dict= {} 
  for i in range(row[n_Steps]):
     val1 = row["val1"]
     val2 = row["val2"]
     val3 = otherfunction(val1, val2)
     res_dict[i] = {"val1":val1, "val2":val2, "val3":val3}  
  return res_dict
```

I then use this function with pandas `.apply()`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df = df[columns_in_question].apply(function)
```

The new DataFrame should have more rows than the original one.

I tried putting the return values from `function` in `pd.Series()` and `pd.DataFrame()`, but with no result

The error message is

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

How can I create a new DataFrame with `.apply()` and a function that returns multiple new rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df[columns_in_question].apply(function, axis = 1).tolist())
```

This will create a dataframe with column names 0, 1, 2, etc, since your function returns a dictionary with keys 0, 1, 2...